# SWIG: Automatic argument wrapping

Tags: c++, arguments, swig

Consider the following two classes

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#ifndef SWIG
class Foo
{
public:

    explicit Foo( const char * const arg ) : arg( arg )
    {
        cout << "create a foo class" << endl;
    }

    void print_foo( void ) const
    {
        cout  << "this is a foo class: " 
              << static_cast<const void*>( this )
              << " - " << arg
              << endl;
    }

private:
   string arg;

};
#endif

class Bar
{
    public:

    Bar()
    {
        cout << "created a Bar class" << endl;
    }

    void function_one( const Foo & c1 )
    {
        c1.print_foo( );
    }


    void function_two( const Foo & c1 )
    {
        c1.print_foo( );
    }


    void function_three( const Foo & c1 )
    {
        c1.print_foo( );
    }


    void function_four( const Foo & c1 )
    {
        c1.print_foo( );
    }

};
```

I would like to make the Bar class available to a scripting language with SWIG.
In this example, Foo can be seen as a special string class, which shall not be available/visible on the scripting side. 
In order to do this, I could create some wrapping functions in my bar.i file:

```
%module bar
%include "typemaps.i"


%{
  #include "bar.hpp"
%}




class Bar
{
   public:

    Bar();



    void function_one( const char * const arg )
    {
       function_one( Arg_Class( arg ) );
    }

    void function_two( const char * const arg )
    {
       function_two( Arg_Class( arg ) );
    }

    void function_three( const char * const arg )
    {
       function_three( Arg_Class( arg ) );
    }

    void function_four( const char * const arg )
    {
       function_four( Arg_Class( arg ) );
    }

    void function_one( const char * const arg )
    {
       function_one( Arg_Class( arg ) );
    }

};
```

But is is not nice, because it needs a lot of copy-pasting.
Is there a way to tell Swig, that it automatically creates such wrapping?

It would be nice if can do something like

```
%module bar
%include "typemaps.i"

%{
  #include "bar.hpp"
%}

%include "bar.hpp"
```

and all arguments of type Foo are automatically wrapped, that the methods can be called with a`char*` argument.

Comment: I guess your original problem is different, but what you need above is an input typemap, where a temporary Foo objects is made from const char*.

Comment: Is it deliberate that the constructor of Foo isn't marked explicit? (Makes it easier)

Comment: The explicit keyword was missing.
The documentation (http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_nn8) says _Typemaps can't be used to define properties that apply to C/C++ declarations as a whole._
The document refers to _Customization Features_, but I have no idea how to apply that to this problem.